# GNU Make does not include all auto-generated includes before executing dependent rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My makefile makes use of auto-generated dependencies. To do this, I have in my top-level makefile something similar to:

```
# Makefile
include target1.deps
include target2.deps

all: target2.deps
    cat $^

target2.deps: target1.deps
target1.deps:
    echo "target2.deps:" > $@
    echo "  touch target2.deps" >> $@
```

Initially, `target1.deps` and `target2.deps` do not exist. When make is first instantiated, it parses the entire Makefile and searches for a way to generate these include files. After building them, it reinvokes itself, causing the Makefile to be reparsed and the include files to be included this time. At least, that's my understanding.

The issue is that when I run the above Makefile, Make first builds `target1.deps`, then executes the body of the `all` rule, never having built or included `target2.deps`. This causes `cat` to error: `cat: target2.deps: No such file or directory`

This seems like a contradiction to me. I explicitly tell `Make` that `all` depends on `target2.deps`, but it attempts to execute the rule before satisfying its prerequisites!

The intended behavior is that `target1.deps` should be built *and included*, then `target2.deps` should be built *and included* using the rule contained within `target1.deps`, and then `all` should be run. How do I achieve this?

---

**Context**: Since this is weirdly abstract, here's my goal: I have a target `index.html`, which gets generated from a template `index.html.in`, but I don't know anything about its dependencies. I need to find out (a) which files I need to create before building `index.html` and (b) which files `index.html` will depend on at runtime.

For example `index.html` includes some inline css that's pulled out of `global.css` - I need to therefore build `global.css` before building `index.html`. On the other hand, `index.html` links to `about.html`, so after I build `index.html` I want to also build `about.html`. I call the former "build dependencies" and the latter "runtime dependencies". So my makefile looks something like this:

```
include index.html.build_deps
include index.html.runtime_deps

all: index.html $(runtime_deps_index.html)

%.build_deps: %.in
    ./extract_build_deps %< -o %@
%.runtime_deps: %
    ./extract_runtime_deps %< -o %@

%: %.in
    ./compile_template %< -o $@
```

What I want to happen is for Make to follow these steps:

1. Build `index.html.build_deps`
2. Include `index.html.build_deps`
3. Build `global.css` (now a known prerequisite of `index.html`)
4. Build `index.html`
5. Build `index.html.runtime_deps`
6. Include `index.html.runtime_deps`
7. Build about.html (contained inside `$(runtime_deps_index.html)` included from `index.html.runtime_deps`)
8. Target `all` is reached

What actually happens:

1. Make sees that `index.html.build_deps` can be directly build from `index.html.in`; does so.
2. Make sees that `index.html.runtime_deps` can be built from `index.html`, can be built from `index.html.in`.
3. Make builds `index.html`. It errors because `global.css` hasn't yet been built.

If `Make` had included `index.html.build_deps` after building that, then it would be aware of the `global.css` dependency. But because it tries to build *all* include files before expanding any of them, it's unaware of the dependency. I want to add a dependency "index.html.runtime_deps depends on index.html.build_deps *having been included*, but I'm not sure how to specify such a dependency.

Comment: Worth noting is that if I remove `target2.deps: target1.deps`, Make aborts with `No rule to make target 'target2.deps'` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  At what point in your makefile does `target2.deps` ever get created/updated?

Comment: You have no recipe to create `target2.deps`, so it is not created. The empty rule `target2.deps: target1.deps` lets `make` think that is enough to make `target1.deps` to somehow have `target2.deps` also. If you remove it, `make` correctly becomes aware that in fact you specified no way to create `target2.deps`.

Comment: To be clearer: if you remove the empty rule `target2.deps: target1.deps` it fails at first pass, because you have no rule to make `target2.deps`. If you leave it, the rule specified in `target1.deps` is ignored, because, having successfully passed the first pass and its `include target2.deps`, `make` thinks `target2.deps` has already been built.

Comment: I'd call this *spaghetti dependencies*. This is hard to understand and tangled. Why do you need this? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Jens I agree it's an ugly situation. I added some more context with respect to the actual problem I'm trying to solve. If you see a better approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

@Dario is correct.  To be a bit more specific, these are the steps make will follow here:

1. Read the makefile.
2. Try to build target1.deps.
3. Find a target `target1.deps` and execute the recipe.
4. The recipe succeeds, but make observes that the file `target1.deps` still does not exist, so make doesn't mark the target as updated.
5. Try to build target2.deps.
6. There's a target for it that depends on `target1.deps`, which make already built, but there's no recipe for it so make doesn't mark `target2.deps` as updated (since it was never updated, as far as make can tell--it didn't run any recipe to update it).
7. So, make decides none of the included makefiles were actually updated and it won't re-exec.
8. Then make wants to build `all`; it sees that `all` depends on `target2.deps` but make already considered that target and decided it didn't need to be rebuilt, so now make is done with all its work.

You can run `make -d` and follow along with the decisions make takes.